# gitlab-ci multi java version

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab-ci

I have an question about gitlab-ci, my java project should support different java version because these is necessary and i struggle to setup gitlab-ci correctly.
My gradle builder works on my personal computer but on gitlab or jitpack it did even fail the job.
My Project have these structure

```
Protectionlib (ProjectName):
   Core (Java8):
      gradle.build
   LocalLibary (Java8):
      gradle.build
   PlotSquaredv3 (Java8):
      gradle.build
   PlotSquaredv4 (Java8):
      gradle.build
   PlotSquaredv6 (Java17):
      gradle.build
```

There is my gitlab repo i try to build: https://gitlab.com/Ste3et_C0st/protectionlib/-/tree/master on my computer the job is builded successful, i have defined the used java version in the gradle.build over sourceCompatibility & targetCompatibility.

I hope someone can help me about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` the line `export GRADLE_USER_HOME=pwd/.gradle` is not correct, you can just remove the line.
see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables

that line is mixing system-home with local gradle project cache